# check object existance when function retuning pass by reference

Tags: c++

I have very basic issue and have following code. In rare cases, we are not able to call setDriver(set driver object) and call getDriver function for calling driver class function which resultant memory crash( as setdriver has not set). is it possible to check getdriver object. I have tried to set NULL but as we are returning reference it's not appropriate/feasible.

```
include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Driver {
private:
 string name;
public:
  void setname(string name);
  void display();
};

void Driver::setname(string name)
{
  this->name = name;
}

void Driver::display()
{
  cout<<" This driver is .."<<name<<endl;
}

class sample {
protected:
Driver *m_d;
public:

void setDriver(Driver *driver);
Driver& getDriver();
};

void sample::setDriver(Driver *driver)
{
   m_d = driver;
}

Driver& sample::getDriver()
{
   return *m_d;
}

int main()
{
  sample s;
  Driver *d = new Driver;
  d->setname("test");
  s.setDriver(d);
  Driver &d1 = s.getDriver();
  // How can I check if d1 is exist or not 
  d1.display();
}
```

**After getting input from below discussion, I have modified code into following way. will it be correct solution?**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Driver {
private:
 string name;
public:
  void setname(string name);
  void display();
};

void Driver::setname(string name)
{
  this->name = name;
}

void Driver::display()
{
  cout<<" This driver is .."<<name<<endl;
}

class sample {
protected:
Driver *m_d;
public:

void setDriver(Driver *driver);
Driver& getDriver();
sample();
};

sample::sample()
{
  m_d = NULL;
}

void sample::setDriver(Driver *driver)
{
   m_d = driver;
}

Driver& sample::getDriver()
{
   if(m_d)
     return *m_d;
   else
         throw "Error";
}

int main()
{
  sample s;
  Driver *d = new Driver;
  d->setname("test");
  s.setDriver(d);
  try{
      Driver &d1 = s.getDriver();
      d1.display();
  }
  catch(...)
  {
    cout<<" object is not prsent"<<endl;
  }
```

Comment: If the pointer can be null then you should return a pointer and check if it's null. References can't point to nothing.

Comment: if I set m_d =NULL in sample class than getDriver returning reference will it be correct? than d1 will be assigning to NULL which is also not correct

Comment: This seems bad programming practice

Answer (score 2):

References can't point to nothing so I suggest two options:
a) throw an exception - this for me is clearly the best solution; this is an edge case and very appropriate for exception handling
b) Include a method driver.isLoaded() which the caller can check - in the case when you can't allocate a driver return a stub driver which returns this value as false

Alternately you need to change the nature of the call to return a pointer (so that you can return null) or pass your driver as a reference parameter and return a boolean to indicate success. Neither of these options seems as good as a above to me.

Comment: Or have a constructor to ensure that the pointer always exist

Comment: you mean, exception in getDriver. will be it better if we check m_d in getDriver and throw exception if not exist. it will not impact other piece of code.

Comment: @Elemental, Can you give me reference for suggested solution

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami I think it makes most sense to throw an exception from inside getDriver if you can't get one - I think you should be able to find a standard library exception which is appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

A safe way to don't have to check if pointer is null is to force it to never be:

```
class sample {
public:
    // No default constructor

    explicit sample(Driver &driver) m_d(&driver) {}

    void setDriver(Driver &driver) { m_d = &driver; }
    Driver& getDriver() { return *m_d; }
private:
    Driver *m_d;
};
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    Driver d1;
    d1.setname("test1");
    Driver d2;
    d2.setName("test2");

    sample s(d1);
    s.getDriver().display();
    s.setDriver(d2);
    s.getDriver().display();
}
```